# Creating Cluster for Watson Retrieve & Rank service

Tags: retrieve-and-rank

I am new to retrieve & rank api. Just started working on my first tutorial. When I try to create a new cluster (free) with 50 mb storage, I get the following error:

Unable to create new Cluster: Incorrect If-Match header

**Reproduction steps:**
1) Click 'Launch tooling' for my retrieve & rank service in Bluemix
2) A new window open. Select the connected 'Document conversion' api. 
3) Click on 'create a new cluster'.
4) Add cluster name & select 0.05 GB in Cluster size dropbox. 
5) Click on 'create' button.

**Results**
Error message: Unable to create new Cluster: Incorrect If-Match header

Comment: Can you provide more information? I ask because when I try to create a cluster, I have no issues. What bluemix region are you in? What web address are you using for Retrieve and Rank? What name are you choosing? Do you still have this problem?

Comment: Thank you very much. For some reason the problem has been resolved. I am able to create a cluster with 0.05 GB size. 

I am using:
Region = United Kingdom
Service name= rank-and-retrieve-service (PLAN - Standard)
Cluster_name = test_cluster (size = 50 MB)

Comment: Glad to hear it is sorted. It could have been a temporary issue that resolved itself and likely nothing to do with your options or account.